# XML not loading into Internet Explorer

Tags: xml, html

I am creating some flash cards using html5 css and a xml page.  This works great in chrome and Firefox but I cannot get it to load in Internet Explorer.  I am not sure if it is the htlm5 code or the xml page that is causing it not to load.  In some cases I am loading images and text in the xml file.  I am wondering if the problem comes from the < qText> tag in the xml file.

Here is the code for the html page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
    <meta name="Author" content="Drew Scott" />
    <title>Chemistry Flash Cards</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HullFlashCards.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HullFlashCards.js" ></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="previous"><img src="img/left.png" width="50" height="52" alt="left" onclick="prevCard()"></div>
        <form name="cards">
        <div class="card" id="card1">
            <div class="cardContent">
                <p class="cardText" ><span id="question"></span></p>
                <img id="img" src="" width="" height="" alt=""/>
                <div id="audioContainer"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="clickForAnswer" onClick="rotateYDIV('card1', 'backOfcard1')" 
            value="Answer"></input>
        </div>

        <div class="backOfcard" id="backOfcard1">
            <div class="backOfcardContent">
                <p class="answer" ><span id="answer"></span></p>
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="clickForAnswer" onClick="rotateYDIV('card1', 'backOfcard1')" 
            value="Question"></input>
        </div>

        <div class="next"><img src="img/right.png" width="50" height="52" alt="right" onclick="nextCard()"></div>
        <input type="button" class="randomize" onclick="clickRandom()" value="Randomize" name="random"></input>
        <input type="button" class="Afirst" onclick="clickAFirst()" value="Answer First" name="Afirst"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlFile;
    xmlFile="chemistry";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",xmlFile+'.xml',false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    questionSwap();

    maxCardNum=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('numOfCards')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue-1;

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

`@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background:#d7d7da;
}
.page {
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    width:480px;
}
.randomize {
    position:absolute;
    top:605px;
    left:90px;
}
.Afirst
{
    position:absolute;
    top:605px;
    right:90px;
}
.card {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:80px;
    width:320px;
    max-width:320px;
    height:600px;
    max-height:600px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:white;
    display:table;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index:1;
}
.cardContent {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:5px;
    max-width:502px;
    max-height:310px;
}

.cardText {
    font-size:22px;
}
.clickForAnswer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    right:5px;
}
.backOfcard {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:80px;
    width:320px;
    max-width:320px;
    height:600px;
    max-height:600px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:white;
    display:table;
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index:0;
}
.backOfcardContent {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    max-width:502px;
    max-height:310px;

}
.answer {
    font-size:26px;
}
#audio {
    max-width:310px;
}
.next {
    position:absolute;
    top:231px;
    right:0px;
    margin-left:30px;
    float: right;
}
.previous {
    position:absolute;
    top:231px;
    left:0px;
    margin-right:30px;
    float:left;
}
#img {
    display:block;
    max-width:310px;
    max-height:590px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;


}`

and here is a sample from the xml page:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cards>
    <numOfCards>48</numOfCards>
    <textCard id="0">
        <question>
            <qText>  </qText>
            <imageSrc>graphics/alcohol thermometer.JPG</imageSrc>
            <imageWidth>54</imageWidth>
            <imageHeight>505</imageHeight>
            <imageAlt>IE doesn't work</imageAlt>
            <audioMp3>none</audioMp3>
            <audioOgg>none</audioOgg>
        </question>
        <answer>
            <aText>spirit-filled (alcohol) thermometer</aText>
        </answer>
    </textCard>`

Comment: Hit F12 with IE, reload and check the error console to find out which problems occur in IE. If you have a sample online you could also post a URL to allow others to check.

Comment: Here an updated live link: http://cite.nwmissouri.edu/projects/flashcards/FlashCards1234/flashcards.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `qText` elements seem to be containing only white space. IE uses MSXML as its XML parser which strips white space text nodes so your attempt to read out `document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('qText')[cardNum].childNodes[0].nodeValue;` gives an error as `childNodes[0]` does not exist. Depending on your needs you can fix the input and put some text into the `qText` elements or you need to try whether doing `<qText xml:space="preserve">  </qText>` fixes the problem or you need to adjust the Javascript code to use e.g.

```
function getText(element) {
  if (typeof element.textContent !== 'undefined') {
    return element.textContent;
  }
  else if (typeof element.innerText !== 'undefined') {
    return element.innerText;
  }
  else if (typeof element.text !== 'undefined') {
    return element.text;
  }
}
```

and then use

```
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = getText(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('qText')[cardNum]);
```

instead of `document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('qText')[cardNum].childNodes[0].nodeValue;`.

Comment: Well that fixed the problem with the images not loading now I cannot get it to flip the card and show the answer.  Got any idea's on why it won't show the answer or show answer first? Also I tried both things you suggested and both worked.  Btw thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you should post a new question with the actual problem, telling us which browsers you tried and which don't work. I tried your sample http://cite.nwmissouri.edu/projects/flashcards/FlashCards1234/flashcards.html with Firefox 25 and the cards are flipped.

Comment: Everything works great in FireFox and Chrome, but the card flip does not work in Internet Explorer, I am using IE 10 for my testing.

Comment: I think you should take out the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`, if you want to use the latest features like CSS animation/transform. Let IE 10 do what it can, don't restrict it to pretend it is IE 9.

Comment: Ok I just took it out but it doesn't appear to have changed anything.  Ultimately I would like it to work in IE 9 because the college I am making this for uses IE 9 as its default.  But at this point I would take IE 10.

Comment: @Drew, I have just visited http://cite.nwmissouri.edu/projects/flashcards/FlashCards1234/flashcards.html with IE 10 and the card flip works.

Comment: And according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, for IE 9 you need e.g. `element.style.msTransform = ..`

Comment: Currently the card does not flip over to the backside but you have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` in there again so the code won't work, even in IE 10, as it is asked to behave like IE 9 which does not support `style.transform`. So currently, the only way to have the code working with IE 10 is to hit F12, set document mode to standard and then the code works. But of course you should simply take out the `meta`, then you have the page working with IE 10. And to have it working with IE 9 you will need to add code setting `style.msTransform`, like you do for `MozTransform`.

Comment: It does work in IE 10 thats great I swear I tried it the last day I was in the office and it didn't work, taking out the meta tag fixed it for IE 10 now I will see if I can get it to work in IE 9.

Comment: So I added msTransform to my css and js and it doesn't work but I am not sure if I have it set up right do you have any idea's I swear if we get this to work it will be the last problem I have :) I updated the css and js to have the msTransform

Comment: @Drew, I am not sure why it does not work with IE 9, other than that you use some stuff like `-ms-transform-visibility` that does not exist respectively is not supported, with IE 10 there is support for `backface-visibility`, a proprietary property of the name `ms-backface-visibility` however does not exist for IE 9. And `-ms-transform-visibility` is not a defined property either. The original problem about the XML loading is solved, if you need help on getting the whole CSS/script stuff working with a particular browser than it is better to post a new question with tags CSS, Javascript, IE.